# delete the space after inserting photo

Tags: floats

I have a problem when inserting figure. a space is displayed after the figure.
Here is the code and the figure displayed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXPVD.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, **compilable** tex code resulting in your problem ...

Comment: Just a guess, but replace [H] with [htp], both here and in the following figure (not shown).

Comment: Use `\raggedbottom`. The equations don't fit the current page and are output on the next page, LaTeX tries to fit the content of this page to be spaced out evenly. But, really, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{sample.png}
    \caption{Baldwin
    witnessed while participating in the Selma voting registration march in
    }
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: How can you be sure this answers the question? The OP might have a spaceship in the document, containing some alien technology, causing the problem. Or maybe a witch cursed the document. Who knows?